# How to resolve GETJson duplicity exception?

Tags: java, json

I am developing a rest server in java, netbeans.

I made my first get method and my class looks like this:

```
@Stateless
@Path("v1/cardapio")
public class CardapioResource {

    private Gson gson = new Gson();

    @EJB
    private CardapioRemote ejb;

    public CardapioResource() {}

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Path("/")
    public String getCardapios(@QueryParam("key") String key) {
        Conta c = ContaDAO.busca(key);

        JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
        if(c != null){
            JsonArray array = (JsonArray) gson.toJsonTree(ejb.findAll());
            obj.add("dados", array);
        } else{
            JsonObject status = new JsonObject();
            status.addProperty("codigo", 401);
            status.addProperty("mensagem", "Não há nenhum ID correspondente a este KEY");
            obj.add("status", status); 
        }
        return obj.toString();
    }

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Path("/")
    public String getCardapios(@QueryParam("key") String key, @QueryParam("id") String id) {
        // second method
    }
}
```

The above method is responsible for validating a fkey in the database and if it is valid returns a list of menus.

So I tried to do the second method, get an id ... and after validated it would return only the menu of the given id. My class looks like this:

```
@Stateless
@Path("v1/cardapio")
public class CardapioResource {

    private Gson gson = new Gson();

    @EJB
    private CardapioRemote ejb;

    public CardapioResource() {}

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Path("/")
    public String getCardapios(@QueryParam("key") String key) {
      // first method   
    }

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Path("/")
    public String getCardapios(@QueryParam("key") String key, 
                               @QueryParam("id") String id   ) {
        Conta c = ContaDAO.busca(key);

        JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
        if(c != null){
            JsonArray array = (JsonArray) gson.toJsonTree(ejb.findById(Integer.parseInt(id)));
            obj.add("dados", array);
        } else{  
            JsonObject status = new JsonObject();
            status.addProperty("codigo", 401);
            status.addProperty("mensagem", "Não há nenhum ID correspondente a este KEY");
            obj.add("status", status); 
        }
        return obj.toString();
    }
}
```

After the inclusion of this second method an exception is occurring :

> WebModule[/webPlataformaCardapio]StandardWrapper.Throwable [FATAL] A
>   resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP
>   method GET and input mime-types as defined by @Consumes and @Produces
>   annotations at Java methods public java.lang.String
>   ws.CardapioResource.getCardapios(java.lang.String) and public
>   java.lang.String
>   ws.CardapioResource.getCardapios(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) at
>   matching regular expression /. These two methods produces and consumes
>   exactly the same mime-types and therefore their invocation as a
>   resource methods will always fail.;
>   source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@4fef476']

Imagine I have a server url servidor:porta/api/produtos?key=1 that validates the key and returns all products ... and I can have the servidor:porta/api/produtos?key=1&id=5 that validates the key and returns only product 5. Both have the same path, with no divisions of "/".

How can I solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message is clear:

> These two methods produces and consumes exactly the same mime-types and therefore their invocation as a resource methods will always fail

You listen to the same path, same HTTP method and mime type for input/output.

You need to make them different so your server can clearly decide which method to call

You could for example add an `id` to the path of the second method.

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("/id")
public String getCardapios(@QueryParam("key") String key, 
                           @QueryParam("id") String id   ) {
...
}
```

But if you want to have only one path, you can create two business methods, one that handles only the `key` and the other that handles the `key` and the `id`.

```
private void businessMethod1(String key) {
    // do your stuff
}

private void businessMethod2(String key, String id) {
    // do your stuff
}

@GET
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("/")
public String getCardapios(@QueryParam("key") String key, 
                           @QueryParam("id") String id   ) {
    if(id == null) {
        businessMethod1(key);
    } else {
        businessMethod2(key, id);
    }
}
```

Comment: But the methods I find on the internet are usually like this... "servidor:porta/v1/consumos/?api_key=GUID&codigo=string&modo_venda=(1 à 4)&ticket_id=GUID&item_id=GUID" ... there is no "/". How can I make various methods using only "&"?

Comment: `servidor:porta/v1/consumos/` is the path and `?api_key=GUID&codigo=string&modo_venda=(1 à 4)&ticket_id=GUID&item_id=GUID` are the parameters. In your case, you only have one path, which is why you get en error. - If it's unclear, post the url you want to use to access to your application

Comment: Got it. Imagine the following, I can do like this:"server:port/v1/consumes/?Api_key=GUID&code = string" or
"server:port/v1/consumes/?Api_key= GUID&code=string&sales_modem=1... both would have the same address ... but in my head would be two methods, no?

Comment: No, it's a single method but only for getCardapios. You can create two business methods, one that takes 2 parameters and one that take 3. I'll update my anwser